# Can composite video output emulate 30Hz vertical / 33,557Hz horizontal security camera output?

Tags: composite-video

I have an unused composite video input on my Swann security DVR.  I would like to populate it with information gathered by my 1st generation Raspberry Pi with composite video output.

I put an oscilloscope on one of my Swann security cameras and evaluated the video output.  I noted the vertical sync frequency is 30Hz and the horizontal frequency is 33,557Hz.  Vpp was 2.53V.

As NTSC is (was) 60Hz vertical and ~15Khz horizontal - I assume the normal Raspberry Pi composite video output is unsuitable for the Swann DVR.

So, is there a way to alter the first generation Raspberry Pi composite video output?  I see there are many options for the HDMI output.  But I have not found any explanations WRT to changing the frequencies of the Raspberry Pi's composite video output.

-thanks

Comment: what happened when you connected the RPi? ... never assume anything

Comment: ...don't know.  Assume it would not work.  First I'll check the Vpp and if the RPi's composite output is close or less than 2.53 I'll give it a try.